# simple_form not displaying error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

My first time posting here!

I have a form, with a lot fields and it's working great unless any validation error occurs...

If "validates_presence_of" is raised, a "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in ..." page is opened and leaves my form...

How can I get errors shown on the same page/form (as always)?

All the best!

**My controller**

```
    if check_cadastro == "Válido para cadastro"

       code....

      if @usuario.save!
        session[:usuario_id] = @usuario.id
        cookies[:token] = @usuario.token
        render :action => "edit"
      else
        render "new"  
      end  
   end
```

**MY VIEW**

```
<%= simple_form_for @usuario do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div ><%= f.input :cnpj, input_html: { class: 'txt' } , :label => false %></div>
    <div ><%= f.input :razaosocial, input_html: { class: 'txt' } , :label => false %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) instead of [save!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) so the if statement can fail, your object will contain messages in its [errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages) object, and `simple_form` can render them next to each form input after `render :new`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
save!
```

which throws errors, to:

```
save
```

which returns false or true, with object correctly validated, so you can access errors with:

```
@user.errors
```